# Using a video device in 2 applicatrions simoultaneously with Gstreamer

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, video-capture, nvidia-jetson, v4l2loopback

I am trying to use the camera feed on my Jetson Nano (running headless over SSH) in 2 different applications.

From the command line, I am able to run

```
gst-launch-1.0 nvarguscamerasrc ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=3280, height=2464, format=NV12, framerate=(fraction)21/1' ! nvvidconv ! xvimagesink
```

Which streams video from my camera (IMX219 connected to the Jetson Nano) to my desktop via an X11 Window.

What I would like to do is somehow use that same video stream in 2 different applications.
My first application is a python program that runs some OpenCV stuff, the second application is a simple bash script which records video to an *.mp4 file.

Is such a thing possible? I have looked into using `v4l2loopback`, but I'm unsure if that is really the simplest way to do this.

Comment: gstreamer has a T element from where you could move  in 2 direction's. For example 1 appsink and 1 filewriter sink?

Comment: just for the record: the *T* element mentioned by @Micka is really called `tee`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I managed to figure it out thanks to both commentors, here is my solution on my Jetson Nano, but it can be tweaked for any Gstreamer application.

First, use `v4l2loopback` to create 2 virtual devices like so:

```
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback video_nr=1,2
```

That will create `/dev/video1` and `/dev/video2`

Then you use `tee` to dump a Gstreamer stream into each of these virtual devices, here is my line:

```
gst-launch-1.0 nvarguscamerasrc ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=3280, height=2464, format=NV12, framerate=(fraction)21/1' ! nvvidconv ! tee name=t ! queue ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1 t. ! queue ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video2
```

This is specifically for my Jetson Nano and my specific camera, but you can change the gstreamer pipeline to do what you wish